# Let 0<a<b<c be 3 distinct digits. The sum of all 3 digit numbers formed by using all the 3 digits once each is 1554. What is the value of c?

Tags: number-theory, permutations, combinations

The options for the answer are as follows:-

(A) 3
(B) 4
(C) 5
(D) 6

By seeing the options, I can deduce that c will be less than or equal to 6 and greater than or equal to 3.
First, I assumed that c is equal to 3. There are only 2 options for (a,b) i.e. (1,2). Using Brute force, I got the correct answer as (A).

Is there a way to solve this question in a more mathematically rigorous manner. Can I solve this without using the options at all?

Comment: "*I got the $\color{red}{\text{correct}}$ answer as (A)*"  What makes you think (A) is correct?  It is not correct by my count.  Note: $123+132+213+231+312+321=1332\neq 1554$

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I think I made an error in my calculations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your proof is not really a proof at all, since you already claim you **assumed** that $c$ is equal to $3$. In fact, (A) is an incorrect answer, since if $c=3$, then $a=1,b=2$ and the total sum would then not be $1554$, it would be $1332$.

You can't just **assume** what the answer will be! What if you assumed $c$ is equal to "dinosaur"?

---

The $6$ numbers are $abc,acb,bac,bca,cab,cba$. We can write $abc=100a + 10b + c$ which means the sum  of these $6$ numbers is equal to

$$200(a+b+c) + 20(a+b+c) + 2(a+b+c)=222(a+b+c)=1554$$

which means that $a+b+c=7$. Since $a,b,c$ are distinct, this leaves very few options.

Comment: So, c should be equal to 4, right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes

---

c should be 4 because the only option of having *a+b+c=7* is `a=1, b=2 and c=4`